# How to merge excel sheets with dissimilar headings.

Tags: excel-2013

I've got several dozen excel sheets/tabs in one workbook that is output from an image analysis package and I would like to merge them all into one master sheet. While brute force copy and paste would work, I will be outputting several hundred pieces of data that will come in this format and a streamlined approach would be very beneficial.
Starting format; sheet one of the workbook might look something like this:

X  | Y  |  Z

12  |5 |    9

14  |8  |12

13  |5  |11

sheet two, which is in the same workbook but under a different tab would be

A | B | C

4  | 9 |  1

2 | 4 | 8

3  | 2  | 1

What I would like is for the sheets to be merged into one workbook/ one tab that has the same number of rows and just places the new values in a new set of columns adjacent to the original ones (each sheet has the same number of rows since the data is simply about different aspects of the same items)

X | Y | Z | A | B | C

12 |5 |  9 | 4 | 9 | 1

14 |8|12  | 2 | 4 | 8

13 |  5  | 11 | 3 | 2|  1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply reference to the worksheet where you want to copy data from. Drag the crosshair till the desired position.

```
='Sheet2'!A1
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the below script and save it to Merge.vbs. You can drag and drop excel files on top of this script file to merge them. The first data row must contain column names. Columns with no column name will be skipped. The script will create a new "Combined" sheet at the beginning. If the next worksheet will contain a column name not present in the previous sheets a new column will be added.

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 then
    MsgBox "Please drag and drop an excel file on top of this script file to merge sheets."
    WScript.Quit
End If

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFilePath = WScript.Arguments(0)

If fso.FileExists(sFilePath) = False Then
  MsgBox "Could not file Excel file: " & sFilePath & " to merge sheets"
  WScript.Quit
End If

If MsgBox("Merge worksheets for this file: " & sFilePath, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then
  WScript.Quit
End If

Dim dic: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim oExcel: Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Visible = True
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = false
Set oWorkBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)

Set oCombined = oWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(oWorkBook.Worksheets(1))
oCombined.Name = "Combined"
dic("Sheet Name") = 1
oCombined.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Sheet Name"
oCombined.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
iRowOffset = 0

For Each oSheet in oWorkBook.Worksheets
    If oSheet.Name <> "Combined" Then
        iRowsCount = GetLastRowWithData(oSheet)

        For iRow = 1 to iRowsCount
            If iRow = 1 And iRowOffset = 0 Then
                'Sheet Name header
            Else
                oCombined.Cells(iRow + iRowOffset, 1).Value = oSheet.Name
            End If
        Next

        For iCol = 1 to oSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            sCol = trim(oSheet.Cells(1, iCol).Value & "")

            If sCol <> "" Then 'Skip columns with no data

                If dic.Exists(sCol) Then
                    iDestCol = dic(sCol)
                Else
                    iDestCol = dic.Count + 1
                    dic(sCol) = iDestCol
                    oCombined.Cells(1, iDestCol).Value = sCol
                End If

                For iRow = 2 to iRowsCount
                    oCombined.Cells(iRow + iRowOffset, iDestCol).Value = oSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
                Next
            End If
        Next

        iRowOffset = iRowOffset + iRowsCount - 1
    End If
Next

MsgBox "Done!"

Function GetLastRowWithData(oSheet)
    iMaxRow = oSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If iMaxRow > 500 Then
        iMaxRow = oSheet.Cells.Find("*", oSheet.Cells(1, 1),  -4163, , 1, 2).Row
    End If

    For iRow = iMaxRow to 1 Step -1
         For iCol = 1 to oSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            If Trim(oSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value) <> "" Then
                GetLastRowWithData = iRow
                Exit Function
            End If
         Next
    Next
    GetLastRowWithData = 1
End Function

Function GetLastCol(st)
    GetLastCol = st.Cells.Find("*", st.Cells(1, 1), , 2, 2, 2, False).Column
End Function
```